# WebView Twitter slow loading

Tags: iphone, twitter, webview

I have a WebView loading a Twitter mobile user's wall:

```
NSString *urlAddress = [NSString stringWithString:@"http://mobile.twitter.com/gatrecords"]; 
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[myWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

When web is loaded it freezes for 10- 15 secs then I can navigate normally. On the iPhone's Safary Browser happens the same. That behavior only happens with loading mobile.twitter plus a user's wall.

On the simulator all is ok.

Any suggostions on what could be wrong ?

Comment: UIWebView Class Reference: JavaScript execution time is limited to 10 seconds for each top-level entry point. If your script executes for more than 10 seconds, the web view stops executing the script.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for the freezeing. Apparently WebView freezed bacause tries to execute twitter's javascript for 10 seconds, after that time the system will stop trying and the WebView will be scrollable. So I stopLoading only when twitter's web is being loaded:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

  NSString *twitter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[myWebView request] URL]];

  if ([twitter isEqualToString:@"http://mobile.twitter.com/gatrecords"]) {
       [myWebView stopLoading];
  }
}
```

Then I get an error alert after the 10 seconds regarding javascript did not load correctly, I fix that as follows:

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

 [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.alert=null;"];
```

}

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using an iPhone 3G with 4.2.1. I don't know if the same problem happens on 3GS or 4.